# Functional Programming in JavaScript - events

Tags: javascript, events, functional-programming

I've been reading a fair amount about advantages of functional programming, and am trying to write some code which adheres to what might be considered functional programming. Immutability, Pure Functions, Local States, etc.

The particular problem I have is as shown below. I'm not sure if there is some way to do what I want without breaking those rules. I guess I'm here to find that out.

```js
let mouseDown = false;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', () => mouseDown = true);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => mouseDown = false);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  if (mouseDown) console.log({ x: e.movementX, y: e.movementY });
});
```

After spending 10+ years working with OOP, I'm finding it very hard to get a hand of FP. However, that's beside the point.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there a better way to solve this particular problem using functional programming?
2. Should we be concerned about using functional programming **everywhere**?

Comment: events aren't a good fit for FP as pure functions couldn't do anything besides hit the event target...

Comment: There are some areas where imperative programming is better suited and FP on others.Events must have state that's where FP is hard to apply.

Comment: 1) Look into functional reactive programming. 2) Being dogmatic is never a good idea.

Comment: @ftor I agree about being dogmatic being a bad idea. I've looked into functional reactive programming and decided that I will learn Elm to get a better idea about that. There's an Elm meetup in my city soon! Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

Rxjs will fit in here for the code

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html

Normally you register event listeners.

```
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('Clicked!'));
```

Using RxJS you create an observable instead.

```
var button = document.querySelector('button');
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click')
  .subscribe(() => console.log('Clicked!'));
```

What makes RxJS powerful is its ability to produce values using pure functions. That means your code is less prone to errors.

**Purity**

```
var count = 0;
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(`Clicked ${++count} times`));
```

Using RxJS you isolate the state.

```
var button = document.querySelector('button');
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click')
  .scan(count => count + 1, 0)
  .subscribe(count => console.log(`Clicked ${count} times`));
```